# Shortest code for finding a certain value in an array using regex?

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have an array with these elements:

```
[
    'whatever',
    'something else',
    'foobar'
]
```

I know I can iterate over the array and check for foobar using a regex for example. The question is, is there a shorter way of doing that?

Thanks?

Comment: Does it need to be regex?  Why not [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/array_search)?

Comment: I have to use a substring of the full string in each element.

Comment: Check for it within a string in the array? And what do you want to do if you find it?

Comment: Take a look at [**array_filter**](http://pt2.php.net/array_filter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php

$items = [
    'whatever',
    'something else',
    'foobar'
];

$matches  = preg_grep ('/foobar/', $items);
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

You don't need to iterate over the array, you can use preg_grep and pass your array instead.

Happy coding

Comment: What a great solution, +1!

Comment: Yes, nice one. One question: How can I get the result from the returned array? foobar for example as string?

Comment: I didn't know `preg_grep` existed.  What a neat function! :-)

Comment: @user1856596 what do you mean by that? $matches is an array containing all the items of the given array, that matched the regex

Comment: `preg_grep()` is indeed the right way to go about it!

Answer (score 1):

Not regex , but still worth a mention

```
if(in_array($string,$array)) {
    //is shortest i can think of 
}
```

OR

```
$your_var = in_array($string,$array) ? 'this is foo' : 'something else';
```